# Is it possible to combine or nest multiple "@-rules" in CSS ... so different "@" are required before executing rule?

Tags: css

For instance, how would I make both "@" conditions required?:

```
@supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
  .widget-wrap {}
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1366px) and (max-device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  and (orientation: landscape)  {
  .widget-wrap {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN's "At-rules" CSS Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule#conditional_group_rules):

> [Conditional Group Rule] statements share a common syntax and each of them can include nested *statements*—either *rulesets* or ***nested at-rules***.

So you should be able to write it as:

```css
@supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 1366px) and (max-device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  and (orientation: landscape)  {
        .widget-wrap {}
    } 
}
```

As [user Heretic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey) correctly points out, it is worth noting that this applies *only* to [**CSS Conditional Rules** as defined by a W3 modules of the same name](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-conditional-3/), which as of June 2021 includes [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media), [`@supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports), and the now [deprecated `@document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document) rules; **other at-rules are *not* nest-able.**

Comment: It should be noted that the rule applies only to those at-rules listed on that page (technically, the CSS Conditional Rules Module Level 3 recommendation) (`@media`, `@supports`, and `@document` at the time of writing), so no one tries nesting something under `@charset` or something silly.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - thanks, good callout.  I tried to be specific in the quote by referring to "Conditional Group Rules," but it is definitely worth extra note; I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
@supports (something) {
  @media only screen and (other conditions) {
    .widget-wrap {}
  }
}
```

It works the other way around as well:

```
@media only screen and (other conditions) {
  @supports (something) {
    .widget-wrap {}
  }
}
```

Or you can nest deeper if needed:

```
@media only screen and (other conditions) {
  @supports (something) {
    @media only screen and (other conditions) {
      .widget-wrap {}
    }
  }
}
```